# Unable to import FANN in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, binding, neural-network, fann

I have tried installing FANN Python bindings on Ubuntu using all of apt-get install, pip, and directly from source, but the same error keeps occurring when I try to import FANN. Namely, it tells me that fann_copy is undefined (the following is the specific error):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from fann2 import libfann
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fann2-1.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/fann2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fann2 import libfann
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fann2-1.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/fann2/libfann.py", line 28, in <module>
    _libfann = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fann2-1.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/fann2/libfann.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_libfann', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fann2-1.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/fann2/_libfann.so: undefined symbol: fann_copy
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem than you, and resolved it this way.

I basically followed the installation process of FANN that you can found [here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/installing-fann/), and did the following :

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/fann/fann/2.2.0/FANN-2.2.0-Source.zip
unzip FANN-2.2.0-Source.zip
cd FANN-2.2.0-Source/
cmake .
sudo make install
```

Te be sure that FANN is well installed :

```
cd examples/
make runtest
```

Then, install swig:

```
sudo aptitude install swig
```

(I had swig2.0, swig3.0 and installed just swig after, I don't think it helps since FANN seems to look for swig2.0 binary, but who knows ?)

Then install python bindings :

```
sudo aptitude install pip
sudo pip install fann2
```

Now, it should be fine.

I think I had the same error because i used an old version of FANN (I blindly followed [this](http://jansipke.nl/installing-fann-with-python-bindings-on-ubuntu/) tutorial).

Hope this helped.